# Remove hostnames from URL with sed/awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression, perl

I got lists of urls with different domains and I want the hostname removed with sed, awk or something similar and only keep the path. There are no urls with port or username@password in it.

input:

```
http://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/
http://example.com/blog/
https://example.com/blog/
https://www.example.co.uk/blog/
https://example.co.uk/blog/
https://sub.example.co.uk/blog/
https://www.example.com/blog/
https://www.example.com/cases/page/4/
https://www.example.com/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/cv/result/7c9123dc38da6841
https://www.example.com/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/jsd/7fe83wdcs/invisible.js
https://www.example.co.uk/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/jsd/7fe83wdcs/invisible.js
https://sub.example.co.uk/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/jsd/7fe83wdcs/invisible.js
```

output should be:

```
/
/
/blog/
/blog/
/blog/
/blog/
/blog/
/blog/
/cases/page/4/
/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/cv/result/7c9123dc38da6841
/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/jsd/7fe83wdcs/invisible.js
/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/jsd/7fe83wdcs/invisible.js
/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/jsd/7fe83wdcs/invisible.js
```

I hope someone can help me because I can only find regex commands. I don't know how to convert these correctly to a sed or awk command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `perl`:

```bash
perl -pe 's|^([^/:]+:)?//[^/]*||' < your-file
```

Would remove an optional scheme (to take care of both `http://host/path` and `//host/path`) followed by `//` followed by all the characters  other  than `/` that follow (would remove the `host` and also the `user:password@host:8080` in `ftp://user:password@host:8080/pub` for  instance).

A `sed` equivalent could be:

```bash
LC_ALL=C sed 's|^\([^/:]\{1,\}:\)\{0,1\}//[^/]*||' < your-file
```

In any case, the `s/pattern/replacement/` operator of both `sed` and `perl` take regular expressions for the pattern, so called *basic regular expressions* for `sed`, *perl regular expressions* for `perl` (which improve and extend  the *extended regular expressions* that many `sed` implementations also support with the `-E` option these days).

There's also a `URI` module for `perl` which you can use to parse a URI into a structured object.

```bash
perl -MURI -lpe '$_ = URI->new($_)->path' < your-file
```

Note that it discards the query string (as in `http://host/path?query`) and fragment  (as in `http://host/file.html#anchor`) if any. Replace `->path` with `->path_query` if you want the query if  any to be included.

Comment: scheme is not (just) a word; rfc3986 says it can contain (noninitial) `+- .` but not `_` and (unsurprisingly) https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml conforms to that rule

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085, I've changed it to [^/:] which I'd expect should be enough if lines are meant to contain URIs.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to do with linux coreutils:

`cut -d '/' -f 3- somefilewithyoururls.txt | sed 's/^/\//'`

Cut everything after the third `/`, then replace the start of the line with a `/`.  No need for complicated regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's:[^/]*//[^/]*::' file
/
/
/blog/
/blog/
/blog/
/blog/
/blog/
/blog/
/cases/page/4/
/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/cv/result/7c9123dc38da6841
/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/jsd/7fe83wdcs/invisible.js
/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/jsd/7fe83wdcs/invisible.js
/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/jsd/7fe83wdcs/invisible.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -MURL -ne 'my $url = URL.new($_); put "/" ~ .path.join("/") for $url;'  file
```

Sample Output:

```perl
/
/
/blog
/blog
/blog
/blog
/blog
/blog
/cases/page/4
/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/cv/result/7c9123dc38da6841
/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/jsd/7fe83wdcs/invisible.js
/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/jsd/7fe83wdcs/invisible.js
/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/jsd/7fe83wdcs/invisible.js
```

For Raku, loading the `URL` module might be the cleanest answer, as it can handle usernames/passwords in the url. Above, the recognized `path` element is both preceded-by and `join`ed-on `/` forward_slash, then out`put`.

Simplifying the code above lets you know what elements are recognized:

```perl
~$ raku -MURL -ne 'my $url = URL.new($_); .raku.put for $url;'  file
URL.new(scheme => "http", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "www.example.com", port => Int, path => [], query => {}, fragment => Str)
URL.new(scheme => "https", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "www.example.com", port => Int, path => [], query => {}, fragment => Str)
URL.new(scheme => "http", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "example.com", port => Int, path => ["blog"], query => {}, fragment => Str)
URL.new(scheme => "https", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "example.com", port => Int, path => ["blog"], query => {}, fragment => Str)
URL.new(scheme => "https", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "www.example.co.uk", port => Int, path => ["blog"], query => {}, fragment => Str)
URL.new(scheme => "https", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "example.co.uk", port => Int, path => ["blog"], query => {}, fragment => Str)
URL.new(scheme => "https", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "sub.example.co.uk", port => Int, path => ["blog"], query => {}, fragment => Str)
URL.new(scheme => "https", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "www.example.com", port => Int, path => ["blog"], query => {}, fragment => Str)
URL.new(scheme => "https", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "www.example.com", port => Int, path => ["cases", "page", "4"], query => {}, fragment => Str)
URL.new(scheme => "https", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "www.example.com", port => Int, path => ["cdn-cgi", "challenge-platform", "h", "g", "cv", "result", "7c9123dc38da6841"], query => {}, fragment => Str)
URL.new(scheme => "https", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "www.example.com", port => Int, path => ["cdn-cgi", "challenge-platform", "h", "g", "scripts", "jsd", "7fe83wdcs", "invisible.js"], query => {}, fragment => Str)
URL.new(scheme => "https", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "www.example.co.uk", port => Int, path => ["cdn-cgi", "challenge-platform", "h", "g", "scripts", "jsd", "7fe83wdcs", "invisible.js"], query => {}, fragment => Str)
URL.new(scheme => "https", username => Str, password => Str, hostname => "sub.example.co.uk", port => Int, path => ["cdn-cgi", "challenge-platform", "h", "g", "scripts", "jsd", "7fe83wdcs", "invisible.js"], query => {}, fragment => Str)
```

If you really dare to parse URLs with a regex (are you certain no data has been maliciously crafted?), then the following is a rather direct translation of the Perl answer posted by @Stéphane_Chazelas:

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's|^ ( <-[/:]>+ \: )? \/ \/ <-[/]>* ||;'  < file
```

https://raku.land/cpan:TYIL/URL
https://raku.org